# Choosing a hosting a reactjs, nodejs application

Tags: node.js, web-hosting, web-applications

I have application built with reactjs, nodejs and mysql db, currently I am hosting it on godaddy VPS. The main reason why we had to go for their VPS, because we already had a legacy app on their shared server, but when we upgraded our node version they did not support the version on shared platform so we had to switch to VPS.
But while working with this I am feeling that I have to manage everything which BTW was the contract.

I am looking for alternatives with lower costs, and equipped with some features as part of the service like email DNS to send emails, without me needing to configure a DNS or MX server, also having SSL as part of the service without me needing to add certificates. Ability to upgrade node version.

Can someone help me to find out if there is any provider where I can host my application?

Comment: Sorry, no. Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Ok, may I ask where can I check this? apart from googling generally.